# Serialize custom exception to JSON with web api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, custom-errors

I need to show custom property added to custom exception `ModelException` at the output json of my `WebApi`. So I created custom exception class as follows

```
 [Serializable]
public class ModelException : System.Exception
{
    private int exceptionCode;
    public int ExceptionCode
    {
        get
        {
            return exceptionCode;
        }
        set
        {
            exceptionCode = value;
        }
    }

    public ModelException() : base() { }

    public ModelException(string message) : base(message) { }

    public ModelException(string format, params object[] args) : base(string.Format(format, args)) { }

    public ModelException(string message, System.Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }

    public ModelException(string format, System.Exception innerException, params object[] args) : base(string.Format(format, args), innerException) { }


    protected ModelException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        if (info != null)
        {
            int result = 0;
            int.TryParse(info.GetString("ExceptionCode"), out result);
            this.exceptionCode = result;
        }
    }

    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    public override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info != null)
        {
            info.AddValue("ExceptionCode", this.exceptionCode);
        }

        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }

    public ModelException(string message, int exceptionCode)
        : base(message)
    {
        this.exceptionCode = exceptionCode;
    }
}
```

then add the following configration to my `WebApiConfig`

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        {
            IgnoreSerializableInterface = true
        };
```

the issue here is the new overidden constructor with `SerializationInfo` parameter is not fired and the newly custom property is not appear in the returned `Json` from `WebApi`

Comment: One of the mechanism that I use to achieve the same is using the Web API Error filters, which can intercept the call on exception and can be used to modify the Context.Response, with necessary exception information, check:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling

Comment: Don't you need to set `IgnoreSerializableInterface = false` instead?

Comment: @dbc yes i tried setting `IgnoreSerializableInterface = false` but nothing worked the custom property doesnt apear

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I tried adding custom filter to intercept the call on exception but with no luck to show the custom property in the final json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @MrinalKamboj

In order to change the output Json of `Web API` in the case of `Exception`. I did the following changes to solve this

1. Implement my `Custom Exception (ModelException)` as in my Question
2. as per @MrinalKamboj comment i created the following

   ```
   public class NotImplExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
   {
       public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
       {
            if (context.Exception is ModelException)
            {
               ModelException exception = (ModelException)context.Exception;
               HttpError error = new HttpError();
               error.Add("Message", "An error has occurred.");
               error.Add("ExceptionMessage", exception.Message);
               error.Add("ExceptionCode", exception.ExceptionCode);
               error.Add("ExceptionType", exception.Source);
               error.Add("StackTrace", exception.StackTrace);

               context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error);
            }
       }
   }
   ```
3. register the attribute to `Web API` as follows

   ```
   config.Filters.Add(new NotImplExceptionFilterAttribute());
   ```

**The explanation of the issue**

I want to change the output `json` resulted from `Web API` this will not be  applicable by just implementing `ISerializable` we need to intercept the exception and change the output response of the json using `HTTPErorr`